# What are the limitations of the theming system?

Tags: theming

- Can every theme function in include/theme.inc be overridden by a template (*.tpl) file?
- Can preprocess functions be used to add variables to any theme function?

Comment: What is it you're asking, exactly? Your question doesn't have any context, so it's hard for anyone to offer any help.

Comment: i am sorry,i forgot to say it's about drupal.

Answer (score 2):

Theming hooks (templates and *theme functions*) defined in [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6) implementations are always overridable. But they have to be used properly, always use `theme('foo', $bar)`, never `theme_foo($bar)`.

In Drupal 6, (pre)process functions are only available for templates, not *theme functions*. Also, the templates must be be overriden in the theme otherwise the preprocess function from the theme is not used. So to have your `THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables)` function used, you need to have the `node.tpl.php` in your theme folder.

Another limitation (actually a bug) is that for a template to be overridable in a theme, the file name (without the `.tpl.ph`p extension) must be exactly the same as the theming hook name except for the `_` that are replaced by `-`:

```
function MODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'overridable_template' => array(
      'template' => 'overridable-template',
    ),
    'non_overridable_template' => array(
      'template' => 'nonoverridable-template',
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, but you have to register the template file by implementing [hook_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6).
2. No, according to http://drupal.org/node/223430, "Preprocess functions only apply to theming hooks implemented as templates".

Comment: This is only correct for Drupal 6 and below.

Comment: @tim.plunkett Yes, this is only correct for versions of Drupal that have already been released by the time I answered this question.

Comment: Whoaaaa didn't notice this was migrated from stackoverflow. That makes much more sense now! Sorry if I seemed abrupt.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes.

2) In Drupal 7, there is the new [`hook_preprocess()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7), which can be used for any theme or template function. For example, `theme_checkbox()` can be preprocessed by `YOURTHEME_preprocess_checkbox()`.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, they can. As with any theme function defined from other modules, you can override them with a template file if you implement [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7).
- As reported in the documentation for [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7)

> If the implementation is a template file, several functions are called before the template file is invoked, to modify the `$variables` array. These fall into the "preprocessing" phase and the "processing" phase, and are executed (if they exist), in the following order (note that in the following list, HOOK indicates the theme hook name, MODULE indicates a module name, THEME indicates a theme name, and ENGINE indicates a theme engine name):